# VSTS - REST API - Assign Test Case to multiple Test Configurations

Tags: azure-devops

Using the REST API documentation I am able to create a test case (workitem) in Visual Studio online and assign it to a Test Suite. I can also create Test Configurations.

On the visualstudio.com site I can assign a Test case to multiple Test Configurations (there by essentially creating multiple instances of the Test).

Is there a REST API method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn’t such REST API available in VSTS, there is the uservoice that you can vote: [VSTS REST API assign test configurations to test case](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32668729-vsts-rest-api-assign-test-configurations-to-test-c)